# How can I wrap divs with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a slider out of divs that are looped out with PHP. I don't know the number of divs that will be looped out so I am trying to figure out how I can make a slider out of this.

I dont want to copy/paste my whole loop. So in this QA/Example I will use images and code examples.

Lets say my output looks like this. Where the black border is the visible screen area. And the red borders the divs from the php loop. This divs are looped out in the container `#container`.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:300px;
            height:600px;
        }

        .item {
            height:100px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            float:right;
            margin:24px;
        }
```

Now, I want to create a slider that slides in the divs 4 by 4. I figure that the best way to do this is to group the divs 4by4 using a wrapper lets say its class is `.wrapper` and to move the divs besides the first one out of the visible screen area use `.absolute-pos`. To add some position absolute values. Like this where the yellow border is the `.wrapper`:

[image]

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}

.absolute-pos {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left:320px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

And now to my Question:

How can I, using jQuery. Create a functions that go tru all the divs in `#container` and then put the divs inside the div `.wrapper` 4by4? And also put the `.absolute-pos` on all divs besides the first one (that should be visible by default)?

Here is a jsfiddle with all the example CSS and the example "loop": http://jsfiddle.net/8k95ktwk/

**EDIT:** To be clear about the questions, this is what I am asking:
 1. How can I add a parent div with the class `.wrapper` to the `.item` divs 4by4?
 2. How can I add the class `.absolute-pos` to all `.wrapper` divs, but not the first one?

Comment: i think it is can be done with css only but you can style both of case and add/remove css class by jquery

Comment: Wow, why is my question getting voted down? I think I explained my issue pretty well? Did'nt I?

Comment: Questions with no code examples of what you have tried tends to be voted down. Why not just hide anything greater than 4 and page with show/hide? Or wrap on the server which makes more sense

Comment: @daremachine yes ofcourse. But what I am asking is 1. How can I create a parent div, for my loop-divs 4by4? and How can I add a class to all of this divs, but not the first one?

Comment: you use bad forum.. if your question is teoretic so use programmers or whatever but stackoverflow is coding help

Comment: If you have command over php then in that loop you can wrap it with another div right and then you can style it with css to look inline.

Comment: ok so you can use jquery functions  .wrap and .not

Comment: @mplungjan yes I know :P That is why I wrote and explained why I did'nt use code. :) But okay I will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a for loop that increments in 4's then wrap using the `.wrapAll()` function.

```
var divs = $(".item");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 4) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 4).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
}

$(".wrapper:not(:first)").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('absolute-pos');
});
```

Have a look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/8k95ktwk/8/)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for. But yoy forgot 1 part of the question. How can I add .absolute-pos to all .wrapper divs. But not the first?

Comment: @JohanGudmundsson  Have a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/8k95ktwk/8/

Comment: Thanks that is perfect! I will give your answer the green mark. But please update it with the rest of your jsfiddle code. In case someone else find this QA in the future  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k95ktwk/1/ .

Comment: I dont think you did understand the question. Read it again please  :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated the fiddle as needed. Used  `.clone()` to achieve it

http://jsfiddle.net/8k95ktwk/7/

Comment: Your answer was good thanks! But there was a other much more simple solution in a other answer  :)

Comment: That is absolutely True... :) !